# Very simple jquery post() (trying to send html to another page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http-post

I am struggling with the `post()` method.

I've been reading several posts on here and the jquery forums, and just trying to get a simple piece of code working is proving difficult. My ultimate goal is to pass a div #exportData and all it's children to test.php.

I started with:

```
$.post("ajax/test.php", $("body").html());
```

To my mind this should return the entire contents of the current page to test.php (unless test.php requires a holding div or element to receive the content). Currently it only returns the blank page.

I then tried looking at the parameters for `post()` if I need to manipulate these:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax/test.php,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        dataType: dataType
    });
```

Also declared a variable:

```
var data = { 
        html: #exportData
    };
```

That bit failed of course. I don't know how to define the data in the parameters, or if this is the right place to do it.

Although I would have thought if:

```
 $.post("ajax/test.php", $("body").html());
```

would have worked then presumably I can substitute "body" for any class, id or selector I like.

Also does the submit button need certain parameters to tie it to the post function. At the moment it is purely:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="send" name="submit">
```

Sorry this is such a basic question.

Comment: You'll need to show the code for the page `ajax/test.php` in order for us to help. I think you have some further exploring to do around web forms in the first place, this will help you understand how the submit button works and how it's all linked together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
var html = $("body").html();
var data = { 
        html: html
    };
$.post("ajax/test.php", data);
```

as the second parameter of $.post() is an object wich contains the data you want to send to the server.

To send the data you could do:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="send" name="submit">
```

js

```
$('input#submit').click(function(e){
  //prevent submitting the form (if there is a form)
  e.preventDefault();
    var html = $("body").html();
    var data = { 
            html: html
        };
    $.post("ajax/test.php", data);
});
```

server side you receive the data

```
 $html = $_POST['html']
```

Comment: I can't get this to work :( I actually disabled the preventDefault action as I wanted to see the test.php page load with the posted content within it now the current page is reloaded and the url is appended with: ?submit=send. The code is online now, so I can send a url for testing.

Answer (score 0):

[$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) expects an object to be passed to transfert data along with the post request:

> **jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )**
>   
>   **url:** A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
>   **data: A map or string that is sent to the server with the request.**
>   **success(data, textStatus, jqXHR):** A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.
>   **dataType:** The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

```
var content = $ ('body').html(),
    data = { content: content };

$.post('ajax/test.php', data);
```

Comment: "data: A map **or string** that is sent to the server with the request." seems to indicate that a string will work fine, though sending an entire page worth of HTML is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Send entire body = proves that the concept works, send div with an id would be a smaller subset of the page. Although granted it could still be alot of characters.

Comment: I do think it is a bad idea too to send the whole page html, or even just a part of it. I can't figure out why the OP wants to do that. But technically it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sending html in the post doesn't sound like a good idea. All elements type of `input` or `select` will be empty in the Html. You would need to use `.serialize` in order to get the values.

```
$('#submit').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'ajax/test.php',
       data: {
           html: $('body').html()
       }
    });        
});
```

Comment: At this stage there are no form elements in the data I am trying to pass to the page, merely html, I have read about characters being changed which I would want to avoid.